# Custom loop of a single category, cannot order by date. What am I missing?

Tags: categories, wp-query, order

I'm going nuts.

All I have is a simple loop on the home page of the site (which is a static page), and it should show the most recent (1) post of a certain category. The trouble is no matter what i do, it seems including category parameter makes sorting by date not work.

This is the loop I am using:

```
<?php
    $announcements = new WP_Query();
    $announcements->query('showposts=1&cat=4');
    while ( $announcements->have_posts() ) : $announcements->the_post();
?>
```

The oldest post always shows up when using this. I have tried adding `&orderby=date` and `&order=DESC`, but nothing works until I remove the `&cat=4`, at which point things are sorted by date just fine.

Am I missing something, or is sorting a single category by date not possible?

Comment: Is 4 a custom taxonomy?

Comment: Nope, just regular old posts.

Comment: Hmm, your code works fine for me. Are you sure you have more than one post in category 4?

Comment: I'd tend to agree with @vancoder, you may only have 1 post in category 4. Try removing that and adding `&orderby=date&order=DESC`. Does it work then?

Comment: I definitely have more posts than 1 in that category. Removing the `&cat=4` causes date sorting to work normally, but obviously shows all posts.

Comment: Well yes, removing the cat=4 would allow posts for any category, so it wouldn't matter if there was only one post in cat #4. Your code looks sounds to me, so if you are sure there are multiple posts available in cat 4, then I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't work, chances are you do not have at least one post linked to that specific `category 4`.

If you wanted to sort by `DESC` and by `date`, you wouldn't have to specify those as arguments in the query because those are both the defaults for sorting.

Also, instead of initializing a `WP_Query` object and simply using the query method, try to get in the habit of passing an array of arguments to the constructor.

So in your case, try the following:

```
$args = array('cat' => 4, 'posts_per_page' => 1);
$announcements = new WP_Query($args);

if ($announcements->have_posts() ) : while( $announcements->have_posts() ) : $announcements->the_post(); ?>    
    <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
    <div class='post-content'><?php the_content() ?></div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Note, I did two things:

1. Created an `$args` array and passed it to the `WP_Query` constructor.
2. Check whether or not it returned any posts by doing `if ($announcements->have_posts())` before the while loop.

Take a look at this for lots of information on the `WP_Query` class http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/14/using-wp_query-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
global $post;
$myposts = get_posts( 'numberposts=1&category=1' );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
    the_title();
    the_content();
endforeach;
```